# Regarding symbols used for current amplification factor

Tags: transistors, amplifier

We just studied basic semiconductors on the high school level and we ended on transistors and we got three notations alpha beta gamma which corresponds to three different transistor arrangement with common base emitter and collector, now surely there must be some reason why common emitter arrangements current amplification factor is called beta while common base is alpha and commin collector is gamma can someone tell me the historical reason for these assigned symbols or any physical interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

The **alpha**, **beta** and **gamma** are not actually representing the same thing.

1. In a common emitter, you input base current and take the output somehow related to collector current. So, Ic/Ib = **beta** becomes your current amplification ratio for common emitter.
2. For a common base, you input to emitter and take output from collector. The emitter and collector currents are nearly equal. So the amplification ratio is **alpha**, which is a value very close to 1 but less than 1.
3. In common collector configuration, you input the base current and
   get the output from emitter, so the ratio is Ie/Ib which is
   **gamma**, slightly higher than **beta**.

---

```
Ie = Ib + Ic
Ic = beta * Ib // common emitter 
Ie = gamma(beta+1) * Ib // common collector
Ic = alpha * Ie // common base
```

You may find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AXeKUQ7baQ) helpful.

Comment: But that wasn't what i asked for i understand they represent different things i want to know why is no1 called alpha only, is there any significance to assigning that?

Comment: @SOSXX so you're asking something like "history of electronics"?

Comment: On the very earliest transistors which were the point-contact type the only practical way to use them was as common-base and alpha could actually be more than unity up to about 2.5.